# Is there a difference between Senheisser HD 280 PRO and HD 280 Silver?

Tags: headphones

The Sennheiser [HD 280 Pro](http://www.sennheiser.co.uk/uk/home_en.nsf/root/professional_headphones-headsets_headphones_004974?Open&row=2) and [HD 280 Silver](http://www.sennheiser.co.uk/uk/home_en.nsf/root/professional_headphones-headsets_headphones_005327?Open&row=2) appear to be the same headphones from the matching spec list, however in the UK they retail for very different prices.

Is there a difference between the models?

280 Pro:
[image: HD 280 Pro]

280 Silver:
[image: HD 280 Silver]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only difference is that the 2nd pair is silver in color.

What are you going to be using them for?

I have a pair of Sennheiser HD 380 Pros and they are the best headphones I have ever owned. I bought them to use for mixing and mastering my music and they are amazing. After listening to an album with them I had listened to hundreds of times, I heard sounds I had never heard before within the songs.

Comment: Production at night, reference and mixing down. Thanks for the recommendation, I'll have a listen before I make another purchase!

Comment: No problem! I got studio headphones for the exact same reason (my house doesn't have any insulation at all on the inside). I was originally planning to get Audio Technica ATH-M50s after reading a ton of reviews but the guy at the store had me listen to those with a song on my iPod and then the same song with 380s and I could tell a difference. It was very subtle but when producing, subtle things can make world of difference.

Comment: So...it turns out I had a lost pair of 380s that I found when I moved house! A/B tested using http://open.spotify.com/track/5wZbNyht0kr3Tu8BkW4hux - 380s won by a mile. They're far less comfortable for extended use, which is a shame, but I agree with your review - thanks!

Comment: p.s. I believe with 380s I can hear the sustain pedal being depressed on the above recording ;)

Comment: I agree with @Andy about being far less comfortable for extended use, but then again I only use them at night and the difference in quality **DEFINITELY** makes up for them getting a little tight after three hours